# How does sed and read line works in shell?

Tags: shell

I have tried to search it but still doesnt understand on what it does.

In our code, sed is use as this:

```
var1 = $(sed /s/date/date01/g << EOF1
$var1
EOF)
```

and read line is use as this:

```
/src/path | grep  -E "String" | while read line
do { 
.... some functions to do.
}
```

I'm very confused on how it works.

Comment: What kind of shell do you use? For the popular shells (Bash,Ksh,Zsh,Sh, for instance) the syntax is invalid. Maybe it's even your custom shell application, how do we know?

Comment: bash shell language

Answer (score 1):

This is the usage of here document. '<< EOF1' treats everything before next EOF1 as input of command sed.

In your code, sed replaces('s') every('g') 'date' with 'date01' from input which is the value of variable var1. But I suppose it is a typo that the slash before 's' is redundant. And no space should among =.